# Android Studio 2.1 is not opening after updating Java jDK 8?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

Now i updated android studio to 2.1 and JDK to version 8.but android studio is not opening.i changed the environment variable to JDK 8.still its not working.let me know what i did wrong .

Comment: Is it working with lower version of jdk ?

Comment: Any error messages we can look at? It's kinda hard for us to pinpoint the problem given such non specific problem description

Comment: its working lower version of jdk